# How to change the arbitrary value in 3 dimentional matrix to 0 or 1 by using matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix, binary

I have 200x200x200 matrix which has some arbitrary values in each voxel.

I would like to change this value to 0 or 1.

If the voxel has a number lager than 0, it will be 1.
else it will be 0.

Is there anyone how to solve this probelm?

My code is as below.

```
B = zeros(200,200,200); % A is my 200x200x200 data
for i = 1:200
    for j = 1:200
        for k = 1:200
            if A(i,j,k)>0
                B(i,j,k) = 1;
            else
                B(i,j,k) = 0;
            end
        end
    end
end
```

But B is entirely 0.
Which part I should change?

Comment: If I'm understanding your question correctly, this sounds like pretty basic indexing and assignment. Can you give us a [mcve]?

Comment: Sorry..I am a beginner. Could you help me?

Comment: Please show what is in `A`.

Comment: A has arbitrary number between 0 and 1.

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce you problem. Code works fine for me with `A` having values between 0 and 1.

Comment: I solved this problem. Thanks

Comment: If you solved your problem, post the answer and close the question so we dont waste time reading it! Also, the one answer you got is the right question. Please accept it.

Answer (score 1):

matrix is your 200x200x200 matrix of arbitrary values. This will create a logical index of the entire matrix where 1 will indicate a value.
`matrix = matrix ~=0;`